# Select additional columns for a SELECT MIN() statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, group-by

I have this current select:

```
  SELECT MIN(CONVERT(DateTime,SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8))),
         SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
    FROM MyData
   WHERE pName IN (SELECT SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
                     FROM MyData
                 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
```

Where `SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,60)` is the person's ID name and `SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,61,8)` is the date they came in.

There are many times where this data shows up multiple times in the table which is why I want to select the MIN date.

The problem is that there is another column in the table (ID) that I need to be added, but I don't want to group by it because it adds duplicates to the Person's ID.

Is there a way I can do the following:

```
  SELECT ID,
         MIN(CONVERT(DateTime,SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8))),
         SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
    FROM MyData
   WHERE pName IN (SELECT SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
                     FROM MyData
                 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
```

EDIT:

There could be multiple times a person comes through:

```
 ID | NameAndDate
----+-----------------------
  1 | J60047238486 08162013
  2 | J60047238486 08182013
  3 | J60047238486 08242013
  4 | J60047238486 09032013
  5 | J60047238486 10102013
  6 | C40049872351 05302013
  7 | C40049872351 07212013
  8 | C40049872351 07252013
```

My current select pulls:

```
         Name | Date
--------------+---------------------
 J60047238486 | 08/16/2013 00:00:00
 C40049872351 | 05/30/2013 00:00:00
```

But I want to add the ID column for those specific rows:

```
 ID |     Name     | Date
----+--------------+---------------------
  1 | J60047238486 | 08/16/2013 00:00:00
  6 | C40049872351 | 05/30/2013 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nope, you have to either aggregate it in some manner, or group by it. Why would an ID column blow out your grouping?  Unless it's some sort of surrogate key, in which case I don't see why you would want it in your output.

Comment: I will post an example in the question.

Comment: Which `ID` value do you want to select for each group of `SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,60)`?

Comment: Added an edit to hopefully clear things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, 
 CONVERT(DateTime,right (SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8),4) 
                            + SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,4)) D,

SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12) N,

COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)) Cnt,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12) 
                   ORDER By SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8)) rn
FROM
mydata
) v WHERE CNT > 1 and rn = 1;
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b3f/25)

Comment: This one actually worked a lot better. Thanks for this update.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it aint' pretty. You have to run your original query to get the minimum date for each name, and then join that back to your MyData table.  It's particularly ugly because of how you store the data.  Converting your MMDDYYYY string to a data was really fun.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b3f/14)

```
select
MyData.[ID],
t1.theName,
t1.theDate
from
Mydata
inner join
(
select
SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12) as theName,
min (
convert(datetime,
right (SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8),4) + '-' + 
left (SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8),2) +  '-' + 
SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8)),3,2)
))as theDate
from
mydata

where
SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12) in
(SELECT SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
                     FROM MyData
                 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12)
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

group by
SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,1,12) ) t1
ON SUBSTRING(mydata.NameAndDate,1,12) = t1.theName
AND (convert(datetime,
right (SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8),4) + '-' + 
left (SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8),2) +  '-' + 
SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(NameAndDate,14,8)),3,2))) = t1.theDate
```

Comment: It's actually a lot worse, I just dumbed it down a bit for others to understand. I will try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    -- first cte - parsing data
    select
        ID,
        left(NameAndDate, 12) as Name,
        convert(date,
            right(NameAndDate, 4) + 
            substring(NameAndDate, 14, 2) +
            substring(NameAndDate, 16, 2),
        112) as Date
    from Table1
), cte2 as (
    -- second cte - create row_number  
    select
        ID, Name, Date,
        row_number() over(partition by Name order by Date) as rn
    from cte
)
select
    ID, Name, Date
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e627/4)</kbd>**